# Google Sheet AppScrip setFormula Syntax error: SyntaxError: missing )

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

i cant get what im missing with my script (newbie, non-coder, I only get the script in google) here is my script.

GOOGLE SHEET appscript

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("INVENTORY OUT");
ss.getRange("B2").setFormula("=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(I:I,'get sloc for picklist'!A:B,2,0),"NO STOCKS")");
```

error message:

> Syntax error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list line: 52
> file: ADD_1.gs

Answer (score 2):

### Solution:

The solution would be to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet15"); 
  ss.getRange("B2").setFormula(`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(I:I,'get sloc for picklist'!A:B,2,0),"NO STOCKS")`);
}
```

In this way everything that is enclosed by the backticks (``) is considered as a type of `string`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use single quotes in your formula definition that is already enclosed in quotes!

```
ss.getRange("B2").setFormula("=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(I:I,'get sloc for picklist'!A:B,2,0),\"NO STOCKS\")");
```

Comment: that is not actually true. This part: `'get sloc for picklist'` **has to** be in single quotes.

Comment: and what about `"NO STOCKS"` ? - I have updated the solution ...

Comment: Well personally I believe template literals make more sense cause you don't need to change anything within the string but most importantly you have the flexibility of using variables inside the string itself. But anyway, I guess it works like that.

Comment: yes soMario, I agree; I upvote your solution